# Have camera move to marker on tap in Flutter Map (Mapbox)

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox

I am using Flutter map package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map), because I don't want to use Googlemaps for this project. The issue is that I have never used it and documentation is pretty poor, so I am having trouble moving the camera to clicked marker:

```
  mapController.move(LatLng(latitude, longitude), 10.0);
```

and of course declaring map controller like this above:

```
MapController mapController = MapController();
```

basically, the move function should work onTap, but it doesn't work for some reason, it gives me some weird runtime error, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
  Widget loadMap() {
...Streambuilder...
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading maps... Please wait');
    for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
      allMarkers.add(Marker(
        width: 45.0,
        height: 45.0,
        point: LatLng(
          snapshot.data.docs[i]['location'].latitude,
          snapshot.data.docs[i]['location'].longitude,
        ),
        builder: (context) => Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons
                      .location_on), 
                
                  color: _markerColor,
                  iconSize: 45.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    
                    //this doesn't work here
                    mapController.move(LatLng(latitude, longitude), 10.0);
                    print(snapshot.data.docs[i]['eventName']);
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                        isDismissible:
                            false, 
                        context: context,
                        builder: (builder) {
                          if (snapshot.data.docs[i]['description'].length >
                              0) {
                            //not the most elegant solution
                            
                          }

                        });
                     //this returns error when marker is clicked, and doesn't move the camera to the marker
                    mapController.move(
                        LatLng(
                          snapshot.data.docs[i]['location'].latitude,
                          snapshot.data.docs[i]['location'].longitude,
                        ),
                        10.0);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
           
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
    return FlutterMap(
     //flutter map displayed with Mapbox
    );
  },
```

}

added map controller in initState, but still getting an error:

```
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = MapController();
  }
```

-the error:

```
The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field '_state@244051772' has not been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      MapControllerImpl._state (package:flutter_map/src/map/map.dart)
package:flutter_map/…/map/map.dart:1
#1      MapControllerImpl.move
package:flutter_map/…/map/map.dart:41
#2      _MapScreenState.loadMap.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:directr/pages/map_screen.dart:67
```

Comment: you should post this on package Github issues.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue, it's just that I am not sure how the code works, since the documentation is poor.

Comment: can you provide the full, minimum reproducible example

Comment: I added full page code. It gets data from Firestore, but for example it doesn't need to, I just want the camera to go to the marker clicked.

Comment: themisir and I are working on the documentation: https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/pull/992. Meanwhile, can you provide the `initState()` code block and the code for the `FlutterMap()`? Also the use of the `StreamBuilder()` may be causing problems, but I'd like to see the other things first. There has been a large number of issues with the controller recently, and solving this issue might also help with the upcoming documentation.

Comment: It's code that I replaced with GoogleMaps, but as I said, I would really like to avoid using those, and use this instead if this is fixed. Init State as far as I remember was just display markers on map function (it works, only the camera doesn't). I would be glad if I helped fix it.

Comment: Ok, can you remember if the way it was was something like the example on this page: https://flutter-map.vercel.app/main-concepts/controller? Please note that those docs (linked) are unofficial and incomplete and should not be used unless otherwise told.

Comment: Let me try it out and I'll get back to you asap.

Comment: Okay, so I have updated the code in the main post, but basically, I am getting this error:

Comment: LateInitializationError: Field '_state@244051772' has not been initialized.

Comment: Looks like you might need to wait for https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/pull/989, or check out the examples like answered below. Unfortunately, there have been errors like this since the null-safety update (some last minute changes were made that weren't tested properly, and we're still finding them now.

Answer (score 1):

A preface: Yes the HTML documentation is not very detailed, but the documentation in terms of code examples it is AMAZING - there are examples for everything. If you are looking for documentation, please also check the "example" folder of any library and the "test" folder - they are most of the time much more useful than the HTML documentation.

Please refrain from using words like "poor" in reference to other peoples work, if you haven't put in the work yourself.

There is a working example [in the "example" folder of the library](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/blob/master/example/lib/pages/map_controller.dart) which I just checked and it is working, if you would like us to fix your specific problem please provide a full example which can be executed.

The code below is altered to be able to run it "standalone" without the other files in the example folder, but no credit goes to me.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
    
class MapControllerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = 'map_controller';

  @override
  MapControllerPageState createState() {
    return MapControllerPageState();
  }
}

class MapControllerPageState extends State<MapControllerPage> {
  static LatLng london = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
  static LatLng paris = LatLng(48.8566, 2.3522);
  static LatLng dublin = LatLng(53.3498, -6.2603);

  late final MapController mapController;
  double rotation = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = MapController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var markers = <Marker>[
      Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: london,
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
          key: Key('blue'),
          child: FlutterLogo(),
        ),
      ),
      Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: dublin,
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
          child: FlutterLogo(
            key: Key('green'),
            textColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: paris,
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
          key: Key('purple'),
          child: FlutterLogo(textColor: Colors.purple),
        ),
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MapController')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      mapController.move(london, 18.0);
                    },
                    child: Text('London'),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      mapController.move(paris, 5.0);
                    },
                    child: Text('Paris'),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      mapController.move(dublin, 5.0);
                    },
                    child: Text('Dublin'),
                  ),
                  CurrentLocation(mapController: mapController),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      var bounds = LatLngBounds();
                      bounds.extend(dublin);
                      bounds.extend(paris);
                      bounds.extend(london);
                      mapController.fitBounds(
                        bounds,
                        options: FitBoundsOptions(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('Fit Bounds'),
                  ),
                  Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        final bounds = mapController.bounds!;

                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                            'Map bounds: \n'
                            'E: ${bounds.east} \n'
                            'N: ${bounds.north} \n'
                            'W: ${bounds.west} \n'
                            'S: ${bounds.south}',
                          ),
                        ));
                      },
                      child: Text('Get Bounds'),
                    );
                  }),
                  Text('Rotation:'),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Slider(
                      value: rotation,
                      min: 0.0,
                      max: 360,
                      onChanged: (degree) {
                        setState(() {
                          rotation = degree;
                        });
                        mapController.rotate(degree);
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: FlutterMap(
                mapController: mapController,
                options: MapOptions(
                  center: LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
                  zoom: 5.0,
                  maxZoom: 5.0,
                  minZoom: 3.0,
                ),
                layers: [
                  TileLayerOptions(
                      urlTemplate:
                          'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                  MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurrentLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrentLocation({
    Key? key,
    required this.mapController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final MapController mapController;

  @override
  _CurrentLocationState createState() => _CurrentLocationState();
}

class _CurrentLocationState extends State<CurrentLocation> {
  int _eventKey = 0;

  var icon = Icons.gps_not_fixed;
  late final StreamSubscription<MapEvent> mapEventSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    mapEventSubscription =
        widget.mapController.mapEventStream.listen(onMapEvent);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    mapEventSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setIcon(IconData newIcon) {
    if (newIcon != icon && mounted) {
      setState(() {
        icon = newIcon;
      });
    }
  }

  void onMapEvent(MapEvent mapEvent) {
    if (mapEvent is MapEventMove && mapEvent.id == _eventKey.toString()) {
      setIcon(Icons.gps_not_fixed);
    }
  }

  void _moveToCurrent() async {
    _eventKey++;
    var location = Location();

    try {
      var currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
      var moved = widget.mapController.move(
        LatLng(currentLocation.latitude!, currentLocation.longitude!),
        18,
        id: _eventKey.toString(),
      );

      if (moved) {
        setIcon(Icons.gps_fixed);
      } else {
        setIcon(Icons.gps_not_fixed);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setIcon(Icons.gps_off);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(icon),
      onPressed: _moveToCurrent,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Please refrain from using words like "poor" in reference to other peoples work, if you haven't put in the work yourself.", I agree, but currently working on the new docs, I can also agree that the current docs are, shall we say, 'somewhat lacking'. Hopefully that will be fixed soon!

Comment: I didn't mean 'poor' as in bad, but as not sufficient, I always appreciate other people's work. I'll check this solution out and get back to you asap. Thank you.